# How to handle an exception when USB-Serial port is removed unexpectedly?

Tags: delphi, exception

My Delphi application (using XE3) needs to handle the EInOutError exception that occurs when a USB-Serial port is removed. The application is used in a test-environment, so cannot rely on an operator to click on the OK button to close the Application Error dialog.

I have tried the following:

- The "try .. except" method - this does not catch these exceptions. I think this does not work because the exception is not caused by the code in the "try" block. It seems to be a lower-level "system-level" exception.
- I tried adding an "ApplicationEvents" component to my form. The OnException method catches a "Custom" exception generated by my application, but not the system-level exception.
- I have also tried adding a global exception hook (as described in [Is it possible to have a global exception hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628751/is-it-possible-to-have-a-global-exception-hook)). This partly works - it allows me to do things **before** the Application Error dialog, but does not stop the error dialog.

I would appreciate any ideas!

Comment: If a try-except block isn't catching the exception, then either the exception isn't occurring where you think it is, it's being caught and handled by other code earlier than you're trying to catch it, or it's not really an exception. Since you can't catch it, how do you know it's an EInOutError exception?

Comment: Do you catch message WM_DEVICECHANGE with DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE type and DBT_DEVTYP_PORT device type when USB-Serial is removed?

Comment: Hi Rob, I get an dialog box titled "Application Error" that pops up. The message inside the dialog is "Exception EInOutError in module Project1.exe at 001C7052." This is running the app outside of the IDE/debugger.

Comment: @MBo I am not familiar with how one detects Windows messages in Delphi. I will try and find out...

Comment: @Rob My test App uses the AsycPro Com-Port component. My simple test app just opens the com port and does not write any data to it. I get the error as soon as the USB-Serial port is removed.

Comment: @Nigel I've written short example as answer

Comment: When the dialog box appears, pause execution of your program. Look at the call stacks of the current threads. You can use that to determine which thread is showing the dialog box and what code path lead to it. Make sure your exception handler is on that code path.

Comment: @RobKennedy Thanks - the call stacks pointed to a solution to the problem. The AsyncPro Com Port component calls a ThreadGone function when the port is removed. This calls a CheckException function which raises the FileIO error. The simplest solution appears to be to modify the component source to handle this error as required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions arising due to USB-Com removal are very annoying. So I'd recommend to eliminate most of reasons for them.

You have to process Windows message WM_DEVICECHANGE and detect port removing. Then set special flag and don't do any operation with port with this flag on! If USB-Com is plugged on again, then reinit serial port. Some code to help:

```
    const
      DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = $8000;
      DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = $8004;
      DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE = $8001;
      DBT_DEVTYP_PORT = 3;

    type
       PDevBroadcastHdr = ^TDevBroadcastHdr;
       TDevBroadcastHdr = packed record
        dbcd_size: DWORD;
        dbcd_devicetype: DWORD;
        dbcd_reserved: DWORD;
      end;

      PDEV_BROADCAST_PORT = ^TDEV_BROADCAST_PORT;
      TDEV_BROADCAST_PORT = packed record
        dbcp_size: DWord;
        dbcp_devicetype: DWord;
        dbcp_reserved: DWord;
        dbcp_name: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
      end;

    ...
    procedure WMDEVICECHANGE(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_DEVICECHANGE;
    ...

procedure TForm1.WMDEVICECHANGE(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  prt: PDEV_BROADCAST_PORT;
  s: string;
begin

  if Msg.wparam =  DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE then
    if PDevBroadcastHdr(Msg.lParam)^.dbcd_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_PORT then
      begin

        b_PortRemoved := True; //check this flag before each operation with port.


        prt := PDEV_BROADCAST_PORT(PDEV_BROADCAST_PORT(Msg.lParam));
        s := prt.dbcp_name;
        ShowMessage('ComPort ' + s + ' has been removed. What can I do?');
    end;

  if Msg.wparam =  DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL then
    if PDevBroadcastHdr(Msg.lParam)^.dbcd_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_PORT then begin
       // USB-COM plugged, you can find it and make some reinitialisation
    end;


end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code! It correctly detects the port being inserted and removed, even if I have not "Opened" the port. However, I still get the Application Error as soon as the port is removed (even though I am not writing anything to it).

Comment: It's rather strange. I use http://sourceforge.net/projects/comport/ and don't see such errors after port removal. May be, your library performs continuous port polling? You can check with http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with Delphi Tokyo and AsyncPro VCL 2022.06 and found a very simple solution. There exists a global exception handler variable GShowExceptionHandler which you can use to avoid the error message.You can find it in  AwUser.pas. Here is a small example of how to use it. Hope this also helps for Borland Builder.

```
uses AwUser;

type
  TReaderException = procedure(ExceptObject: TObject; ExceptAddr: Pointer) of object;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    FOnReaderException:TReaderException;
    procedure OnReaderException(ExceptObject: TObject; ExceptAddr: Pointer);
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FOnReaderException:=OnReaderException;
  // Set global exception handler for AsyncPro
  GShowExceptionHandler:=@FOnReaderException;
end;

procedure TMainWin.OnReaderException(ExceptObject: TObject;
  ExceptAddr: Pointer);
begin
  // do your own exception handling
end;
```